# python script not working on Linux VPS - works on windows

Tags: python, json, linux, discord

I'm unable to get my script to run on my Linux VPS.

Works fine on windows.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# - Import Tools
import discord
from datetime import datetime
import requests
import json as simplejson           


PROXIES = {"http": "PROXY",
           "https": "PROXY"}

headers = {
            'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
            'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'accept-language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9',
            'dnt': '1',
            'referer': 'https://www.goat.com/',
            'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="111", "Google Chrome";v="111"',
            'sec-ch-ua-full-version': '"111.0.5563.64"',
            'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
            'sec-ch-ua-model': '""',
            'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Linux"',
            'sec-ch-ua-platform-version': '"10.0.0"',
            'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
            'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
            'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
            'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
            'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
            }

def search(query):
    url= f'https://ac.cnstrc.com/search/{query.replace(" ", "%20")}?c=ciojs-client-2.29.12&key=key_XT7bjdbvjgECO5d8&i=6ea2c248-7f53-49a6-8150-7cfa7950f77b&s=3&page=1&num_results_per_page=24&sort_by=relevance&sort_order=descending&fmt_options%5Bhidden_fields%5D=gp_lowest_price_cents_4&fmt_options%5Bhidden_fields%5D=gp_instant_ship_lowest_price_cents_4&fmt_options%5Bhidden_facets%5D=gp_lowest_price_cents_4&fmt_options%5Bhidden_facets%5D=gp_instant_ship_lowest_price_cents_4&_dt=1679929318132'

    html = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, proxies=PROXIES)
    output = simplejson.loads(html.text)

    return output['response']['results'][0]

Banner = 'BANNER LINK'
Image = 'IMAGE LINK'
Logo = 'LOGO LINK'
TOKEN = 'TOKEN INSERTED HERE'
CHANNEL_ID = 'INSERT ID HERE'


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.channel.id != CHANNEL_ID:
        return
    
    if message.content.split(' ')[0] == '!goat':
        item = message.content.replace('!goat ', '')
        try:

            product = search(item)

            print(product)

            lowest_price_gbp = product['data']['retail_price_cents_gbp']
            lowest_price = (lowest_price_gbp/100)

            retail_price_gbp = product['data']['lowest_price_cents_gbp']
            retail_price = (retail_price_gbp/100)

            embed = discord.Embed(
                    title= product['value'],
                    url = 'https://www.goat.com/sneakers/' + product['data']['slug'],
                    color=0xb229ce,
                    description='**PRODUCT INFORMATION:**',
                    timestamp=datetime.utcnow()
                )
            embed.add_field(
                name = 'Colour:',
                value = product['data']['color']
            )
            embed.add_field(
                name = 'SKU:',
                value = product['data']['sku']
            )
            embed.add_field(
                name = 'Released (Year):',
                value = product['data']['release_date_year']
            )
            embed.add_field(
                name = 'Retail Price (£):',
                value = lowest_price
            )
            embed.add_field(
                name = 'Lowest Price (£):',
                value = retail_price
            )
            embed.set_thumbnail(
                    url= product['data']['image_url']
                )
            embed.set_image(
                    url=Banner
                )
        
            embed.set_footer(
                    text="Nice1 Pings"
                )
            embed.set_footer(
                    text="Nice1 Pings",
                    icon_url=Logo
                )
            embed.add_field(
                    name="",
                    value="[Twitter](twitter) | [Instagram](instagram)",
                    inline=False
                )
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
        except:
            response = 'An error occurred with your request.'
        await message.channel.send(response)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Have tired with and without proxies and headers.

Have tried to add print statements but doesn't return anything, so I can see what;s happening.

I am getting the response:

'An error occurred with your request.'

Anyone got any suggestions.

works fine on my Windows machine.

Comment: If you remove the `try`/`except`, it will tell you what the error was.  This is why blanket `except` statements are so bad.

Comment: You can try changing the first line to "#!/usr/bin/env python", which should work on both Windows and Linux as it will locate the Python interpreter in the environment.

Comment: @TimRoberts

Removed but still nothing, just 'no errors logged' in the log files.

Comment: Can you run it on a command line from a shell session?

Comment: It actually worked in the end with a reboot. It wasn't actually a coding issue, I had to white list my IP on my proxy providers site